# How to draw a vertical, dotted line down center of page using CSS?

Tags: css

I'd like to draw a dotted line, vertically down the center of my page, "hiding" under any content boxes along the way... Is there a technique to do this in CSS, or will I have to use a repeating image?

Comment: How would the dots have to be?

Answer (score 32):

This gives you dots: http://jsfiddle.net/NBMRp/

```
body:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border-left: 2px dotted #444; /*change these values to suit your liking*/
}
```

They're just not that pretty.

Comment: Nice solution without image request

Answer (score 7):

For the dotted line i would use:

```
.vertical_dotted_line
{
    border-left: 1px dotted black;
    height: 100px;
} 

<div class="vertical_dotted_line"></div>
```

And to make it `under` other elements you need to play with the `z-index` of your dotted line div and the other divs (they should have a higher value of `z-index`)

Comment: it should be just black instead of #black

Comment: @CarlAmbroselli yes indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

If you wants the lines should extend out of div's height -

```
.dashed-lines:after {
content:"";
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: -50px;
bottom: -50px;
left: 50%;
border-left: 2px dotted #ce9b3a;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This can be done either by repeating image or CSS depending on what type of dot you want since CSS has only few types or even single normal dot.

With CSS you can do this by either making the border left or right.

For example

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="tow"></div>
```

CSS

```
.one{
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px dotted red;
}
```

and with image

```
body{
  background-image: url("dotted.png") repeat-y center top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a 1px-wide PNG image in Photoshop with the desired pattern, then set it as the background (or one of multiple background images in CSS3) of the `<body>` element, like so:

```
body {
    background-image: url("dottedLine.png") repeat-y center top;
}
```

You can probably do this without image files by either using a `data:` URI or creating a 2px-tall CSS3 gradient that is repeated.