# Vertical line on top of every other element in body

Tags: html, css, web

Seems  like a popular question without a universal solution. I finished making a website and now trying to add a vertical red line on the left that goes through the whole page. I want it to be a little bit to the right from the border. My attempt is

```
body:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 2%;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
}
```

I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434102/how-to-draw-a-vertical-dotted-line-down-center-of-page-using-css). It works partially. The line does not go through the whole page. I am not sure why. Here is the website I am trying to apply it to ([www.owk.co](http://owk.co/)). The corresponding [github repo is here](https://github.com/KobaKhit/owk.com) in case anybody has the time to look at the index.html. Thanks.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/eqdfhstm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change position to fixed.

```
body:after {
    content:"";
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 2%;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I swear I tried it before and it did not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its happend because its take the 100% of the window height easy solution would be to change the position to `position: fixed;`

```
body:after {
    content:"";
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 2%;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
}
```