# How to touch the inner's div border to the outer's div bottom side?

Tags: html, css

I want to touch the inner's div border to its outer's div bottom side but unfortunately I can't think of any idea how to do it. Here's my code:

```css
.clr {clear:both;}

#timeline {padding-top:50px; display:table;}
.timeline_cont {width:90%;}

.timeline_date_cont {/*float:left;*/ height:100%; width:200px; background:red; display:table-cell;}
.timeline_line_1 {border-right:2px dashed #c3c5c8; height:20px; width:50%;}
.timeline_line_2 {border-right:2px dashed #c3c5c8; height:100%; width:50%;}
.timeline_icon {background:#fff; border:1px solid #000; border-radius:50%; height:20px; line-height:20px; margin:0 auto; padding:3px; text-align:center; width:20px;}
.timeline_date {background:#fff; border-radius:10px; color:#2585fe; margin:0 auto; padding:5px; text-align:center; width:120px;}

.timeline_box_cont {/*float:left;*/ padding-bottom:50px; width:600px; background:blue;display:table-cell;}
.timeline_box {background:#fff; border-radius:10px; box-shadow:0px 0px 20px #c9cbce; line-height:20px; margin:0 auto; padding:20px; position:relative; }
```

```html
<div id="timeline">
    <div class="timeline_cont">
        <div class="timeline_date_cont">
            <div class="timeline_icon">$</div>
            <div class="timeline_line_1">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="timeline_date">6 days ago</div>
            <div class="timeline_line_2">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    <div class="timeline_box_cont"><div class="timeline_box customer_progress_list"><div class="customer_progress_menu_btn">&nbsp;</div><div></div><div class="customer_progress_info">update</div></div></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="timeline_cont">
        <div class="timeline_date_cont">
        <div class="timeline_icon">$</div>
        <div class="timeline_line_1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="timeline_date">6 days ago</div>
        <div class="timeline_line_2">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_box_cont"><div class="timeline_box customer_progress_list"><div class="customer_progress_menu_btn">&nbsp;</div><div>lets see how good this porgress is, lets see how good this porgress is, lets see how good this porgress is, lets see how good this porgress is, lets see how good this porgress is, lets see how good this porgress is, lets see how good this porgress is, lets see how good this porgress is, lets see how good this porgress is, lets see how good this porgress is, lets see how good this porgress is,</div><div class="customer_progress_info">update</div></div></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline_cont">
        <div class="timeline_date_cont">
        <div class="timeline_icon">$</div>
        <div class="timeline_line_1">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="timeline_date">6 days ago</div>
        <div class="timeline_line_2">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_box_cont"><div class="timeline_box customer_progress_list"><div class="customer_progress_menu_btn">&nbsp;</div><div></div><div class="customer_progress_info">update</div></div></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the dotted border below the dollar sign. Actually I want to extend this dotted border and touch it with next below dollar circle. I'm using `display:table` and `display:table-cell` to make divs timeline_date_cont and timeline_box_cont of equal height. But really don't know how to extend timeline_line_1 and timeline_line_2 borders to touch each other top and bottom sides. Any idea?

Comment: I have been trying to fiddle around, all I can tell you now is that `display: table-cell` causes your elements to have some kind of `margin` which prevents the lines from being connected. I tried using Bootstrap to solve this but it seems rather challenging to get it done right. You might want to step away from using anything related to making your document behave like a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Do you want to get something like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/pantyuhind/b9Lyj3fg/14/)

```css
.timeline_cont {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
  background: tomato;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.left:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px dashed #ccc;
  z-index: 0;
}

.timeline_cont:first-child .left:after {
  top: 30px;
}



.timeline_cont:last-child .left:after {
  bottom: 30px;
}


.right {
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
}

.timeline_icon {z-index: 2;position:relative;color:black;background:#fff; border:1px solid #000; border-radius:50%; height:20px; line-height:20px; margin:0 auto; padding:3px; text-align:center; width:20px;}
.timeline_date {z-index: 2;position:relative;background:#fff; border-radius:10px; color:#2585fe; margin:20px auto 0 auto; padding:5px; text-align:center; width:120px;}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="timeline_cont">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="timeline_icon">$</div>
        <div class="timeline_date">6 days ago</div> 
      </div>
      <div class="right">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.      
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="timeline_cont">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="timeline_icon">$</div>
        <div class="timeline_date">6 days ago</div>         
      </div>
      <div class="right">update</div>
  </div>  


  <div class="timeline_cont">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="timeline_icon">$</div>
        <div class="timeline_date">6 days ago</div>         
      </div>
      <div class="right">update</div>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: @10750057 though your solution worked to what I needed but there is still one issue. You have given fixed top and bottom to `timeline_cont:first-child .left:after` and `timeline_cont:last-child .left:after`. The value depends on the content within `<div class="right">`. Since the content is coming from database and due to dynamic in nature these `top` and `bottom` for first and last divs don't work accurately. Sometimes the dotted line doesn't touch the rounded dollar box and sometimes it even crosses the "6 days ago" div. Any way to fix it?

Comment: I also found that the top property always works but its bottom property which sometimes fails due to content size.

Comment: Oh, that's seems strange because I deliberate added the 'Lorem ipsum...' text to consider that case. Also you can add align-items: stretch; to .timeline_cont

Comment: I never heard of this property. I can't find any other solution to fix this strange rare issue.

Comment: Ok, If you never heard about align-itmes, you can read more about flexbox. I believe it helps you find the solution
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

[click the image to see your answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQS0I.png)

You can change the css like this you can also refer the image

```
.timeline_line_2 {
border-right: 2px dashed #c3c5c8;
height: 53px;
width: 74px;
/* padding: 13px 0px 0px 0px; */
background-color: green;
position: absolute;
```

}

Comment: Absolutely wrong answer. You have just given fixed height 53px and it only fixes first div border. Since the content is dynamic and we can't give pre-fixed height, thus your solution will never work.

Comment: Mine solution was for static content ,now you can modify with css for your dynamic content . Just give me some time for better solution sorry to revert you to wrong solution

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434102/how-to-draw-a-vertical-dotted-line-down-center-of-page-using-css) solution I found in another post:

```css
/* Reset Bootstrap props where needed: */

#timeline>.row .col-3,
#timeline>.row .col-9 {
  padding: 0;
}

#timeline .timeline-icon {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

#timeline>.row:first-of-type .col-3:first-of-type>.left {
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/* Actual coding: */

.left {
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}

.left,
.right {
  height: 100%;
}

.timeline-icon {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline_date {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #2585fe;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.timeline-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.left:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 2px dashed #c3c5c8;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" id="timeline">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="timeline-icon">
          $
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_date">
          6 days ago
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="right">
        <div class="timeline-box">
          Foo
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="timeline-icon">
          $
        </div>
        <div class="timeline_date">
          6 days ago
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <div class="right">
        <div class="timeline-box">
          Bar
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zt1fdj9k/)